# Card flip is not working for safari

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written code for card flip.

Here, card flip rotation(3D rotation) is working fine in chrome, firebox, internet explorer but when i open it in **safari**, card flip rotation is not working perfectly.

In safari(**version > 8.0.0**), card is rotated but not with **3d animation.**

Please let me know if any of you have any solutions.

Following is the code:

```js
 $(".btn").click(function() {
   $("#card").toggleClass("flipped");
 });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: transform 1s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
}
#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#card .front {
  background: red;
  font-size: 36px;
}
#card .back {
  font-size: 36px;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
  </div>
</section>

<button class="btn"><span>Flip card</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: i have tested in 8.0.3 and 8.0.7 both.

Comment: -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);transform: rotateY(180deg); try these two browser prefixes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add prefix in webkit and other browsers

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
```

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $("#card").toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
}
#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#card .front {
  background: red;
  font-size: 36px;
}
#card .back {
  font-size: 36px;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
  </div>
</section>

<button class="btn"><span>Flip card</span>
</button>
```